# Looping over a tabular expression and run subquery for each row in KUSTO

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have 2 tables (Tab1 , Tab2) with no common field, I would like to run a query on Tab2 for each row in Tab1 and Where condition in subquery should use column value from outer query.

```
Pseudo code 

tab1
| project timestamp, duration

tab2
| project event_time_t, data

pseudo code/ desired query

tab1 join tab2
| where event_time_t between (tab1.timestamp .. datetime_add('millisecond',toint(tab1.duration),tab1.timestamp))
```

I have checked below options but couldn't got it working

1. MV-Apply : couldn't got it working with tabular expression
2. User defined function : have limitation with changing row context data
3. repeat : works only with scalar

**UPDATE:**

Adding more clarity to my question.

I want to find all rows from T2 which lies between T1.timestamp and add_datetime(T1.timestamp + duration_millisecond)

I did tried the cross join approach and got desired result but its to costly as my T2 table is huge. Can i do this programmatically some how as we do in T-SQL corelated subquery where a subquery gets executed for each row in T1 and change the between clause dynamically with reference to outer query?

```
let T1 = datatable(OperationID:sring,timestamp:datetime, duration_millisecond:int)
[
    1, datetime(2021-02-15T10:56:28.768), 22 ,
    2, datetime(2021-02-15T11:28:28.165), 17 ,
    3, datetime(2021-02-15T12:29:48.954), 90 ,
    4, datetime(2021-02-15T13:30:09.786), 2 ,
    5, datetime(2021-02-15T14:30:22.333), 6 ,
];
let T2 = datatable(event_time_t:datetime, data:string)
[
    datetime(2021-02-15T10:56:28.775), "Some string", 
    datetime(2021-02-15T10:56:28.788), "Another string", 
    datetime(2021-02-15T11:28:28.167), "Yet another string", 
    datetime(2021-02-15T12:29:48.954), "Last string1",
    datetime(2021-02-15T12:29:48.999), "Last string2",
    datetime(2021-02-15T12:29:49.023), "Last string3",
    datetime(2021-02-15T12:29:49.025), "Last string4",
    datetime(2021-02-15T13:30:09.787), "Last string5",
    datetime(2021-02-15T14:30:22.335), "Last string6",
    datetime(2021-02-15T14:30:22.337), "Last string7",
];
T1
| extend temp=1
| join kind=fullouter (
    T2
    | extend temp=1
) on temp
| project-away temp, temp1
| where event_time_t between (timestamp .. datetime_add('millisecond',duration_millisecond,timestamp))
```

Expected Result:

```
Result = datatable(OperationID:sring,timestamp:datetime, duration_millisecond:int, event_time_t:datetime, data:string)
[
    1, datetime(2021-02-15T10:56:28.768), 22 ,datetime(2021-02-15T10:56:28.775), "Some string",
    1, datetime(2021-02-15T10:56:28.768), 22 ,datetime(2021-02-15T10:56:28.788), "Another string",
    2, datetime(2021-02-15T11:28:28.165), 17 ,datetime(2021-02-15T11:28:28.167), "Yet another string",
    3, datetime(2021-02-15T12:29:48.954), 90 ,datetime(2021-02-15T12:29:48.954), "Last string1",
    3, datetime(2021-02-15T12:29:48.954), 90 ,datetime(2021-02-15T12:29:48.999), "Last string2",
    3, datetime(2021-02-15T12:29:48.954), 90 ,datetime(2021-02-15T12:29:49.023), "Last string3",
    3, datetime(2021-02-15T12:29:48.954), 90 ,datetime(2021-02-15T12:29:49.025), "Last string4",
    4, datetime(2021-02-15T13:30:09.786), 2 ,datetime(2021-02-15T13:30:09.787), "Last string5",
    5, datetime(2021-02-15T14:30:22.333), 6 ,datetime(2021-02-15T14:30:22.335), "Last string6",
    5, datetime(2021-02-15T14:30:22.333), 6 ,datetime(2021-02-15T14:30:22.337), "Last string7", 
]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example using two datatables and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can join two tables that don't have a common column, by adding a temp column to both columns with the same value (e.g. `| extend temp=1`), and then `join`ing by this new temp column (e.g. `| join kind=fullouter (...) on temp`).

Here's an example:

```
let T1 = datatable(timestamp:datetime, duration:timespan)
[
    datetime(2021-02-15T10:56:28), time(00:05:00.0102814),
    datetime(2021-02-15T11:28:29), time(00:07:01.0245718),
    datetime(2021-02-15T12:29:48), time(01:00:00.6943432),
    datetime(2021-02-15T13:30:09), time(00:45:02.3022766),
    datetime(2021-02-15T14:30:22), time(00:10:06.2003221),
];
let T2 = datatable(event_time_t:datetime, data:string)
[
    datetime(2021-02-15T11:22:48.4361218Z), "Some string", 
    datetime(2021-02-15T12:23:13.4319484Z), "Another string", 
    datetime(2021-02-15T13:55:54.8762753Z), "Yet another string", 
    datetime(2021-02-15T14:28:13.5785646Z), "Last string", 
];
T1
| extend temp=1
| join kind=fullouter (
    T2
    | extend temp=1
) on temp
| project-away temp, temp1
| where event_time_t between (timestamp .. duration)
```

By the way, note that I simplified your `between` filter so that the right side will contain a timespan, instead of a datetime - it's slightly more efficient, and is easier to read.

Comment: I did checked this approach but issue with this is it will always do a cross join of each row from left table (T1 here) with full table on the right (T2 here). T2 in my case is huge, that is making it quite costly.

Comment: That's what I thought you wanted to do. Apparently it isn't :)  Please edit the question to clarify what you need, and provide sample input (in datatable format) and expected output, elaborate the logic you want, and the approaches you tried. Once you do, please let me know by adding another comment here.

Comment: Updated Question with more details and expected output

Comment: This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/join-timewindow

Comment: Thanks @Slavik N , I tried the time window join but it didn't quite fit my scenario. Anyways, I implemented the logic using Python scripts. Thanks again for all the help.